# How to modify GridSearchCV fit() method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search, hyperparameters

i would like to ask how could i modify the fit() method of GridSearchCV in order to be able to pass some parameters to the custom cross validator. Here is the code snippet that im using:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
skf = CombPurgedKFoldCV(n_splits=10, n_test_splits= 2 ,embargo_td=pd.Timedelta(minutes=100))
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',max_features='auto',class_weight='balanced',min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.)
classifier=BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=clf,n_estimators=1000,max_features=1.,
                         max_samples=avgU,oob_score=True,n_jobs=1)
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid = grid_param, scoring = 'f1',n_jobs = 1, cv=skf)
gs.fit(X,y,pred_times,eval_times)
```

Comment: I think [this article](https://nander.cc/writing-custom-cross-validation-methods-grid-search) would be helpful :)

Comment: It was indeed, Thanks!. One problem i was having is that in here
** `gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid = grid_param, scoring = 'f1',n_jobs = 1, cv=skf)`**

i passed the CombPurgedKFoldCV object rather than the output of **`skf.split()`**. But if i pass the iterable created by skf.split() i get the following error:

**`No fits were performed. Was the CV iterator empty? Were there no candidates?`**

iterable is formated as needed(split() output):

**`yield train_indices, test_indices`**

any thoughts? @meti